# How to write a container that deals with a supertype but also the subtypes?

Tags: c#, type-casting, type

My situation is that i am trying to model an inventory system in a game, In the game there are items that can be placed and retrieved from the players inventory. For example; player inserts a sword item into the inventory, players takes an armor item from the inventory.

I understand that type casting can be used however I would love to know how to do this sort of thing without subverting the type system.

Here is an example: https://dotnetfiddle.net/hR9dBM

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;   

public class Program
{
    public abstract class Item {
        public abstract string GetName();
        public abstract int GetPrice();
    }
    
    public abstract class Weapon : Item {
        public abstract void Swing();
    }
    
    public abstract class Armor : Item {
        public abstract void Wear();
    }
    
    public class Inventory {
        private Dictionary<int, Item> items = new Dictionary<int, Item>();
        
        public void Put(int index, Item item) {
            items[index] = item;
        }
        
        public Item Get(int index) {
            return items[index];
        }
    }
    
    
    
    public class Sword : Weapon {
        override public void Swing() {
            Console.WriteLine("Sword swing");
        }
        
        override public int GetPrice() {
            return 100;
        }
        
        override public string GetName() {
            return "Sword";
        }
    }
    
    public class Breastplate : Armor {
        override public void Wear() {
            Console.WriteLine("Breastplate armor equipped.");
        }
        
        override public int GetPrice() {
            return 200;
        }
        
        override public string GetName() {
            return "Breastplate";
        }
    }
    
    public static void Main()
    {
        Inventory inventory = new Inventory();
        
        // Spawn items
        Weapon item1 = new Sword();
        Armor item2 = new Breastplate();
        
        // Put items into the inventory
        inventory.Put(0, item1);
        inventory.Put(1, item2);
        
        // Get item from the inventory and use it.
        // This is the issue, how to avoid these type casts?
        Item item = inventory.Get(0);
        Weapon itemAsWeapon = (Weapon)(item);
        Sword itemAsSword = (Sword)(itemAsWeapon);
        
        // Use the item
        itemAsSword.Swing();
    }
}
```

Here I would like to avoid the type casting at line 75 to line 77, but i'm not sure how else to implement this? What am i doing wrong here? Thanks!

Comment: First of all, the `itemAsWeapon` is not necessary. Anything you want to do on it, you can do with `itemAsSword`.

Why do you want to get rid of the cast? Calling this in a main() is not the typical use case. Typically, you want to place the item in a sword slot (or something) and when placing that, you need to verify that the Item is actually a Weapon (or maybe even a Sword). The logic to get the Item from the inventory and place it in a Weapon slot would have to check whether it meets the criteria for that slot. I see no issue in having the cast there. Once equipped, you know it's a Weapon.

Comment: @Quido: Given that `Weapon` has an abstract `Swing()` method, I'd be more inclined to argue that you don't need to cast it to a `Sword`, rather than not needing to access it as a `Weapon`

Comment: @Flater: In this case you're completely right. But there is no situation possible where you need the Weapon and there might be situations where you need the Sword. We agree that you only need one.

Comment: @Quido: If there's only one derived `Weapon`, you're right, but it's highly unlikely that that is going to remain the case. If multiple weapon types exist, then accessing the generalized `Weapon` makes a lot of sense (as does the logic involving equipping a _weapon_ specifically).

Answer (score 1):

What you are looking for is a *heterogeneous container*. The most well-known container is probably the `HList`, a *heterogeneous list*.

A heterogeneous container can store elements of different types in a type-safe manner.

For example, if you have an `HList`, and you put an `int`, a `string`, and a `Breastplate` in there, then the list will *not* be of type `List<object>` but rather `HList<int, string, Breastplate>`, and the return type of `get(0)` *will* be `int` and the return type of `get(2)` *will* be `Breastplate`.

There are no heterogeneous containers in the .NET standard collections library, unfortunately, though. I found [an `HList` implementation on GitHub](https://github.com/pocketberserker/Data.HList) that hasn't been maintained since 2018, though. It also includes an `HDict`.

Comment: An hlist is unlikely to be useful in this context, though, as a game would not usually statically restrict specific inventory slots to particular item types.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot avoid these type casts. Without them, the code would never be able to assume anything.

```
Item item = inventory.Get(0);
```

Okay, so we have an item. This code is going to be run for *any* player with *any* possible inventory. So let's focus on two examples:

```
PLAYER 1
    [0] : Sword of Destiny
    [1] : Health Potion

PLAYER 2
    [0] : Mana Potion
    [1] : Wizard's Blade
```

Based on the above code, there is **no reasonable expectation** that the first inventory item is actually a weapon, so your code doesn't make sense, as it inherently requires that first inventory item to be a weapon.

If you didn't want to lose track of where your sword and breastplate are, then you shouldn't have thrown them into the same `Item` collection. It's the logical equivalent of throwing them in a bag and blindly picking out one of the items in the bag. You cannot guarantee that you will get the sword, not the breastplate.

---

While you're always going to have to do some form of casting when retrieving an item, you can improve the consumer's experience by providing a generic type parameter. Something along the lines of:

```
Sword sword = inventory.Get<Sword>(0);

public class Inventory 
{
    private Dictionary<int, Item> items = new Dictionary<int, Item>();
    
    public TItemType Get<TItemType>(int index) 
    {
        // On fail, returns null
        return items[index] as TItemType;

        // On fail, throws exception
        return (TItemType) items[index];
    }
}
```

If the first item is not a sword, you have the option of either returning null or throwing an exception - arguments can be made for either case and it's a contextual decision.

In the end, the consumer still has to know the specific type (which they supply as a generic type parameter), but it is a more elegant syntax.